# UIViewController subviews existance invariant

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

At what point in the `UIViewController` lifecycle is the `subview` property of `self.view` guaranteed to be populated with all the correct views? Note: I don't care about if they're laid out or not, just that they exist in the subview array. WWDC videos say that `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, and `init` all don't come with that guarantee but `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is also late in the game.

The task I'm trying to perform in this instance is localization. In a common view controller class, I want to loop through all the subviews, see if they have a custom attribute set that identifies what localized string key is attached to that view, and then recurse through all that views subviews until the bottom of the view hierarchy is reached. Layout isn't important in this instance, just that the subviews are populated in the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At what point in the UIViewController lifecycle is the subview property of self.view guaranteed to be populated with all the correct views

The earliest point implemented by most apps is `viewDidLoad`. At that point you are guaranteed that `self.view` exists along with all the subviews from the storyboard, *and* that any outlets hooked up to this view controller from the storyboard have been populated.

> I don't care about if they're laid out or not, just that they exist in the subview array

Exactly so. `self.view` and its nib-loaded subviews exist at this point, but their layout has not yet taken place and their frame is not necessarily correct. You don't care, so `viewDidLoad` is fine for your purposes.

Comment: What about this though? https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cx4JzXvWgAASHHv.jpg

Apple's WWDC videos states that in `viewDidLoad`, the view isn't in a superview yet. Does that only apply to `self.view` or is it for all subviews of `self.view` as well?

Comment: To `self.view`. I didn't say in my answer that `self.view` had a _superview_. You asked about `self.view` and its _subviews_ and that is what I answered. It is foolish to assume that `self.view` is _in the interface_ at this point. But you are _not_ assuming it, so you're fine.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I was curious if that restriction not only applied to the view controllers views but it's subviews already. That's good to know, thanks @matt! The reason I was asking is I'm trying to perform localization on views loaded from nibs and if the view is installed for Regular, Regular (iPad only), the views aren't showing up in the list of subviews returned from `loadNibNamed` (I'm using `loadView` as a hook). I thought that might have something to do with it but if both `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` have that invariant, I suppose not.

Comment: Granted that could be some craziness happening not related to `UIKit`, just an issue in the application itself. Wanted to verify and make sure though.

Comment: @startupthekid I do not know what _you_ are doing or seeing. You asked a plain question and I answered it, and I believe you will find that I answered it correctly. Of course if a conditional subview is not applicable to the size class situation at nib-loading time, it won't be present in `viewDidLoad`. Indeed, it might _never_ be present. That is what "conditional" means! But that is a completely different matter.